Reduce time for allocating a c++ 2D vector
The question is fairly simple. For this single line in c++,
std::vector<std::vector<double>> x_vec(10, std::vector<double>(2));

where I create a vector of size (10, 2) to be assigned values.
I found this single operation causes me around 1 microsecond.
I have a function which has several of this to create multiple vectors. Time for single function evaluation is critical for my program.
I found creating this vector was even more expensive than assigning values for it.
How to reduce the time for that? I am not obliged to vectors. Arrays, etc, could be equally good for my case.

which c++ version are you using ? do you need to have jagged arrays ? (each row has different size)

Perhaps you should come up with another algorithm, where you don't have to preallocate vectors this way. Or use another data-structure altogether? Why not a vector with 10 * 2 elements, that you use some simple arithmetic to get each element, and that is always existing and you just reuse it over and over?

I don't need jagged arrays. I am using c++ 14.

Dont allocate it as 2D vector, allocate it as a normal 1D vector and do the indexing yourself (it is not hard)

@Someprogrammerdude, I tried std::vector z_vec(20), roughly the same timing.

@PepijnKramer Interesting. I tried std::vector z_vec(20), roughly the same timing

aside from the mentioned "use 1D vector instead", the most important thing you can do is to re-use allocated memory, either be re-using the same vector or by using some allocator, unfortunately pmr is only available with c++17, so you should just stick with re-using the same vector over and over somehow, maybe with an object pool (search the term)

It's the reuse that will make it better.

consider static variable(s) std::array<std::array<double,  2>, 10> in your function if you know the exact number of 2D arrays the function uses.

Please provide a [mre], including the timing code. As it stands, all we can do is guesswork.

If the size of the memory you need is known in advance as the line you have shown suggests, it would be faster to allocate a fixed size array of doubles on the stack rather than letting std::vector allocate on the heap.
double xy_vec[10][2];

However, you can squeeze most performance out of your function if you don't allocate memory over and over again with every call of your function. Reuse the memory you already allocated and just overwrite it with new values, for example by allocating your data as class members instead of locally inside your function.
